# Agora dá para saber onde estão as strings não traduzidas

Tags: novo-recurso, tradução

Temos uma nova página pra quem estiver interessado em traduzir os site:

### [Traduções Faltando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/translation/missing)

Qualquer usuário pode ter acesso à essa página para ver uma lista das strings do site que **não tem** uma tradução, junto com uma lista das URLs onde ela pode aparecer. Além disso, cada string tem um link que leva direto para sua página no [Transifex](http://www.transifex.com), onde ela pode ser traduzida.

Com isso fica muito mais fácil entender o contexto de cada uma das strings e também de saber onde há lugares onde você pode ajudar a traduzir nosso site. Se você nunca soube por onde começar, a lista de traduções faltando é um excelente ponto de partida.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

A lista não é completa, e algumas strings não vão necessariamente aparecer na URL indicada porque dependem de algum estado específico para aparecerem (strings que só aparecem quando a pergunta está trancada, ou quando já tem votos para fechar, etc), mas ainda assim é uma maneira muito mais prática do que só navegar a lista de strings não traduzidas no Transifex.

O que vocês acham?

Comment: Incrível! Eu comecei a "tentar traduzir" algumas coisas no Transifex há pouco tempo e é muito complicado traduzir sem ter ideia do contexto. Acho que seria interessante colocar o link da página também, ai fica possível abrir a página diretamente.

Comment: Ótimo, toda ajuda é bem-vinda! Ainda preciso explorar melhor, depois dou mais feedback.

Comment: Ótimo recurso Gabe! Recebi muitos 404 e algumas strings já estão traduzidas (esperando revisão, imagino), mas já é um ótimo começo.

Comment: O que aconteceu com esta página, @Gabe?

Comment: @jbueno A última vez que eu tinha acessado (1 mês atrás, acredito) ela funcionava. E a gente não tem planos de matá-la de propósito. Então meu palpite é que alguém deu algum commit errado em algum lugar...

Comment: Menos mal então, vou prestar atenção no número da revisão e quando alterar eu procuro pela página novamente.

Comment: @jbueno Não é porque eu avisei os devs que vai ser consertado no próximo build `:D`

Comment: O que eu quis dizer é que vou esperar pela página

Comment: @jbueno Sem dúvida! Assim que tiver uma solução eu aviso (ou a página voltar ao ar)